# MSSQL server 2008 dissolve sql query

Tags: sql, dissolve, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I have a set of spatial objects in a MSSQL server 2008 R2 trying to dissolve adjoining objects where one of the attributes are equal. The table below is somewhat representative to my original table:

```
id     year     GEOM
01     1999     0x79F...
02     2013     0x79F...
03     1988     0x79F...
04     2013     0x79F...
05     1999     0x79F...
06     2013     0x79F...
```

Many of the objects above are neighbours so I would like to aggregate the spatial objects so that I in the end of the day end up with a smaller number of table entries/objects where possible. I am not looking for myltipolygons.

I have looked around and a propper dissolve functionality like the one available in for example ArcGIS desktop. MSSQL 2008 R2 does not seem to sport this functionality directly.

Is there a way to send a query to the database which does this job for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSSQL server 2008 does not support spatial aggregation. BostonGIS provides a [comparison](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare) between  MSSQL Server 2008, PostGIS and mysql. In this comparison the following is said:

> **Spatial Aggregates (functions like SUM but for spatial)**
>
> Apparently none in this release so have to roll your own with CLR.
> There are numerous examples of this on the web.  UPDATE SQL Server
> 2008 Spatial Tools contains aggregate functions for Union and Envelop
> similar to PostGIS ST_Union and ST_Extent functions

CLR means [Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @ragnvald - I don't know what a CLR is either - just quoting the page. And I missed the CollectionAggregates being in 2012 only, sorry about that.

Comment: @ragnvald - CLR = Common Language Runtime - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx